# How to post ManyToOne entity using JSON format

Tags: json, spring-boot, jpa

I've two entities `issue` and `user` I would like to assign the user to an issue but when trying to do that using this `JSON` the `user_id` in the `issues` table is `NULL`.

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "issues")
public class Issue {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String number;
    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String description;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private State state;
    @JsonIgnore
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column
    private Timestamp createDate;
    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column
    private Timestamp modifyDate;
    @ManyToOne(targetEntity = User.class)
    @JoinColumn
    private User user;

    public Issue() {

    }
```

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    @Column
    private String fullName;
    @Column
    private String username;
    @Column
    private String email;
    @Column
    private String password;
    @Column
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
    @JsonIgnore
    @CreationTimestamp
    @Column
    private Timestamp createDate;
    @JsonIgnore
    @UpdateTimestamp
    @Column
    private Timestamp modifyDate;

    public User() {

    }

    public User(String fullName, String username, String email, String password, Role role) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.username = username;
        this.email = email;
        this.password = password;
        this.role = role;
    }
```

Firstly I've created an user without any issues, but do not know how to manage with the issue here is the JSON I am using via postman.

```
{
    "number": "3",
    "title": "Create an working service",
    "description": "The problem is that we do not have an working service.",
    "state": "NEW",
    "user_id": "1"
}
```

This part is responsible for saving the issue.

```
    public void save(Issue issue) {
        if (issue == null)
            return;
        Issue actual = issueRepository.findByNumber(issue.getNumber());
        if (actual != null) {
            actual.setNumber(issue.getNumber());
            actual.setTitle(issue.getTitle());
            actual.setDescription(issue.getDescription());
            actual.setState(issue.getState());
            actual.setUser(issue.getUser());
            issueRepository.save(actual);
        } else {
            issueRepository.save(issue);
        }
    }
```

In the controller I just have @Valid @RequestBody Issue issue and the service saves the issue.

Comment: You're sending that to what? The code receiving this JSON parses it how? And once parsed, what does it do with it? All this code matters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're sending as JSON is not an `Issue`.

First because it does not represent a database-persistent issue (and that's what the `Issue` class is for), but rather the JSON structure the public API expects from its clients.

Second because an `Issue` doesn't have any field named `user_id`, but your JSON does. So use a *different* class than `Issue`, which actually matches with the JSON structure that the API expects, and thus has a `user_id` property.

Then use this `user_id` to find the `User` by its ID using the `UserRepository`, and set that `User` into the `Issue` you're creating.

I would rename `user_id` to `userId` to respect the Java conventions, too.

Comment: If it's not a problem could you provide me a simple example of that?

Comment: If something isn't clear in my explanations, please tell and ask for clarifications. If everything is understandable, then at least take a few minutes to try it by yourself. Thatt's how one learns.

Comment: But do you have any solution ? except the "easy non-standard" solution you provide above ?

Answer (score 2):

user_id key was not presented in your Item class.
As per entity mapping,
Please change your JSON to this.

```
{
"number": "3",
 "title": "Create an working service", "description": "The problem is that we do not have an working service.", 
"state": "NEW",
"user":{
"fullName":"USER",
"email":"user@gmail.com",
"username":"user"
}
}
```

Comment: but this will insert a new user !  he wants to link the new issue to an existing user.

Comment: @Mehdi it he want to link to the existing user then he need to add `id` attribute aka Primary key in his user JSON.

Answer (score 2):

You need to post json like this.

```
{
    "number": "3",
    "title": "Create an working service",
    "description": "The problem is that we do not have an working service.",
    "state": "NEW",
    "user":{
         "id":1
     }
}
```

Here issue have join column of user so with user entity you have to pass userid.
Your save would be like this.

```
 public void save(Issue issue) {
        if (issue == null)
            return;
        Issue actual = issueRepository.findByNumber(issue.getNumber());
        if (actual != null) {
            actual.setNumber(issue.getNumber());
            actual.setTitle(issue.getTitle());
            actual.setDescription(issue.getDescription());
            actual.setState(issue.getState());
            actual.setUser(userRepositoy.findById(issue.getUser().getId()));
            issueRepository.save(actual);
        } else {
            issueRepository.save(issue);
        }
    }
```